# How to get TransactionScope to work on large sql transactions?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have an app that needs to write to a table on a sql database.  The ID's being used in the IN statement of the sql string needs to be chunked up because there could potentially be 300k ID's in the IN and this overflows the max string length in the web config.  I get this error when i try to test the scenario with 200+k ID's but not with say around 50K ID's:

The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

Heres is the code:

```
    public int? MatchReconDetail(int ReconRuleNameID, List<int> participants, int? matchID, string userID, int FiscalPeriodID)
    {
                DataContext context = new DataContext();
        context.CommandTimeout = 600;



            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {

                Match dbMatch = new Match() { AppUserIDMatchedBy = userID, FiscalPeriodID = FiscalPeriodID, DateCreated = DateTime.Now };
                context.Matches.InsertOnSubmit(dbMatch);
                context.SubmitChanges();

                //string ids = string.Concat(participants.Select(rid => string.Format("{0}, ", rid))).TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', ',' });

                int listCount = participants.Count;
                int listChunk = listCount / 1000;
                int count = 0;
                int countLimit = 1000;


                    for (int x = 0; x <= listChunk; x++)
                    {

                        count = 1000 * x;
                        countLimit = 1000 * (x + 1);
                        List<string> chunkList = new List<string>();

                        for (int i = count; i < countLimit; i++)
                        {
                            if (listCount - count < 1000 && listCount - count != 0)
                            {
                                int remainder = listCount - count;

                                for (int r = 0; r < remainder; r++)
                                {
                                    chunkList.Add(participants[count].ToString());
                                    count++;
                                }

                            }
                            else if (listCount - count >= 1000)
                            {
                                chunkList.Add(participants[i].ToString());
                            }

                        }

                        string ids = string.Concat(chunkList.Select(rid => string.Format("{0}, ", rid))).TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', ',' });

                        string sqlMatch = string.Format("UPDATE [Cars3]..[ReconDetail] SET [MatchID] = {0} WHERE [ID] IN ({1})", dbMatch.ID, ids);

                        context.ExecuteCommand(sqlMatch);

                    }

                matchID = dbMatch.ID;

                context.udpUpdateSummaryCache(FiscalPeriodID, ReconRuleNameID, false);

                transaction.Complete();
            }

            return matchID;
        }
    }
```

I have read some articles suggesting timeout issues so I add the context.CommandTimeout at the top of this function.  The error seems to occur after about a minute after the event fires.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the timeout on transaction too. Not only on command.

You might also have to modify the maximum transaction timeout. The default is 10 minutes, it can be changed in `machine.config` file.

Read [this blog post](http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.se/2012/04/long-running-systemtransactions.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using:

```
    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0,30,0)))
```